# MongodDB Find where fieldvalue > otherfieldvalue*0.5

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm using the [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.find.php) examples for mangodb  like below

```
$where=array( '$and' => array( array(' class' =>12), array('marks'=>70) ) );
$cursor = $collection->find($where);
```

I have two fields: population and male_population
Is it possible to do a search where male_population is greater than 50%? I tried the below but it doesn't seem to work

```
$where['$and'][] = ['male_population' => ['$gt' => 1000]];
$where['$and'][] = ['male_population' => ['$gt' => 'this.population*0.5']];
$cursor = $collection->find($where);
```

also tried

```
$where['$and'][] = "this.male_population/this.population >= 0.5"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution

```
$where['$and'][] = ['$where' => "this.$male_population/this.population >= 0.5"]
```